# React-drid-layout - onClick event

Tags: reactjs

I need to somehow use onClick handler on  from react-grid-layout. The idea - I have a parent , but I can also create new child layouts inside of it. But when I click on parent  (but not on it's item) i should set active layout to 1.

I tried this code:

```
import "./styles.css";
import GridLayout from "react-grid-layout";
import { useState, useRef } from "react";
import "react-grid-layout/css/styles.css";
import "react-resizable/css/styles.css";

export default function CustomLayout({ layout, onDragStart, onDragStop }) {
  const [isDraggable, setIsDraggable] = useState(true);
  const [active, setActive] = useState(2);
  const gridLayoutRef = useRef(null);

  console.log("state", active);

  const handleClick = (event) => {
    const x = event.nativeEvent.offsetX;
    const y = event.nativeEvent.offsetY;
    const layout = gridLayoutRef.current.state.layout;

    for (let i = 0; i < layout.length; i++) {
      const item = layout[i];
      if (
        x >= item.x &&
        x <= item.x + item.w &&
        y >= item.y &&
        y <= item.y + item.h
      ) {
        setActive(2);
        return;
      }
    }

    setActive(1);
  };

  return (
    <GridLayout
      className="layout"
      onDragStart={onDragStart}
      onDragStop={onDragStop}
      layout={layout}
      cols={12}
      rowHeight={80}
      width={1200}
      isDraggable={isDraggable}
      ref={gridLayoutRef}
    >
      {layout.map((item) => {
        if (item.children) {
          return (
            <div
              key={item.i}
              style={{ background: "pink", border: "1px solid black" }}
            >
              <CustomLayout
                layout={item.children}
                onDragStart={() => {
                  setIsDraggable(false);
                }}
                onDragStop={() => {
                  setIsDraggable(true);
                }}
              />
            </div>
          );
        } else {
          return (
            <div key={item.i} style={{ background: "purple", color: "#fff" }}>
              {item.i}
            </div>
          );
        }
      })}
    </GridLayout>
  );
}
```

The idea is simple - i get the coordinates of my click and check if there is a child element. But here comes the issue - onClick event doesn't work. is there any way to solve this issue? I know can create a button to set my state to what i want it to be, but I need something like a clickOut event. 
I'll leave a link to my CodeSandbox example in case someone wants to have a closer look: https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-chatterjee-wzsq62?file=/src/gridLayout.js:0-1882

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on my understanding from the code you posted, onClick event is not being triggered on the parent **GridLayout** and it looks like it's not a clickable element.

What if you wrap the **GridLayout** with a clickable container element, such as a div, and attach the onClick event to that container, something like below:

```
import "./styles.css";
import GridLayout from "react-grid-layout";
import { useState, useRef } from "react";
import "react-grid-layout/css/styles.css";
import "react-resizable/css/styles.css";

export default function CustomLayout({ layout, onDragStart, onDragStop }) {
  const [isDraggable, setIsDraggable] = useState(true);
  const [active, setActive] = useState(2);
  const gridLayoutRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(()=>{
   console.log("state", active);
  },[active])

  const handleClick = (event) => {
    const x = event.nativeEvent.offsetX;
    const y = event.nativeEvent.offsetY;
    const layout = gridLayoutRef.current.state.layout;

    for (let i = 0; i < layout.length; i++) {
      const item = layout[i];
      if (
        x >= item.x &&
        x <= item.x + item.w &&
        y >= item.y &&
        y <= item.y + item.h
      ) {
        setActive(2);
        return;
      }
    }

    setActive(1);
  };

  return (
    <div onClick={handleClick}>
      <GridLayout
        className="layout"
        onDragStart={onDragStart}
        onDragStop={onDragStop}
        layout={layout}
        cols={12}
        rowHeight={80}
        width={1200}
        isDraggable={isDraggable}
        ref={gridLayoutRef}
      >
        {layout.map((item) => {
          if (item.children) {
            return (
              <div
                key={item.i}
                style={{ background: "pink", border: "1px solid black" }}
              >
                <CustomLayout
                  layout={item.children}
                  onDragStart={() => {
                    setIsDraggable(false);
                  }}
                  onDragStop={() => {
                    setIsDraggable(true);
                  }}
                />
              </div>
            );
          } else {
            return (
              <div key={item.i} style={{ background: "purple", color: "#fff" }}>
                {item.i}
              </div>
            );
          }
        })}
      </GridLayout>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thats a good sollution, can't believe i didn't think of it. I also had some mistakes in other logics, but it seems to be alright now (in case somebody will have the same problem - check my codesandbox). Thank you!